# implementing pretty time to format Date time in android

Tags: android

I am implementing pretty time library from this site  [http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) to get a formatted date string with a text in my android application.

I am feeding my date as a string from my local sqlite database,

```
     String dateString="2015-09-25 15:00:47";
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");

     Date convertedDate = new Date();

     try {
         convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     PrettyTime p  = new PrettyTime();

     String datetime= p.format(convertedDate);
     textview.setText(datetime);
```

I want to be able to get my date formatted with `parsetext` like

```
 2 minutes ago
 1 day ago
 ...
```

However the snippet codes above gives me just the text and avoids the time.
This is what it gives

```
 minutes ago
...
```

Please is there something i need to do, I would be grateful if some could help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually passing a date into the `PrettyTime` object, because your date-conversion fails. Confirm that in your logcat.

The problem is that you're passing a different date format and 24h time into this date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
```

You can either change the date format string to use 24h time and match your date format, like so:

```
String dateString="2015-09-25 15:00:47";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
```

or change the time you pass in to be:

```
 String dateString="09/25/2015-09-25 3:00:47 pm";
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what PrettyTime is, but you can use something like this:

```
private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;

public static Date currentDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calendar.getTime();
}

public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;
    }

    long now = currentDate().getTime();
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return "in the future";
    }

    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "Moments ago";
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "A minute ago";
    } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
    } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "An hour ago";
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "Yesterday";
    } else {
        return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will clear all doubt.

```
Date inputDate;
Date outputDate;
String formattedDateString;
String prettyTimeString;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplay);
    String dateString="Sat Mar 18 01:29:01 EDT 2017";
    SimpleDateFormat convertToDate=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
    try {
        inputDate=convertToDate.parse(dateString);
        formattedDateString=newDateFormat.format(inputDate);
        outputDate=newDateFormat.parse(formattedDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrettyTime prettyTime=new PrettyTime();
    prettyTimeString=prettyTime.format(outputDate);
    textView.setText(prettyTimeString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function to do that. try this sample

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Calendar RecordTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            try
            {
                RecordTime.setTime(formatter.parse("2015-09-25 15:00:47"));
            } catch (ParseException e)
            {
                Log.e("EXP",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            long difference = timeNow.getTimeInMillis() - RecordTime.getTimeInMillis();
            long minutesago = difference /(1000*60);
            Log.e("Difference", difference + "");
            txtSyncTime.setText(minutesago + " Minutes Ago...");
```

You can also change the simple date  format in your code to

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
```